# Error C2676 in VC2012 and C2784 in VC2005: reverse_iterator for map of template classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2005

I tried to create an iterator base class as following:

```
template < typename object >
class IteratorBase : public IteratorInterface
{
protected:
    map<int, object> *objectMap;
    //typedef map<int, typename object> objectmap;
    typename map<int, typename object, less<int>, allocator<pair<const int, typename object>>>::reverse_iterator rit;

    //typedef typename objectmap::reverse_iterator riterator;
    //riterator rit;
    //typename objectmap::iterator it;
    typename map<int, typename object, less<int>, allocator<pair<const int, typename object>>>::iterator it;

    UINT32 limit;
    UINT32 start;
    UINT32 count;
    bool reverse;
public:
    ~IteratorBase()
    {
        objectMap = 0;
    }

    object *begin()
    {
        if(objectMap->size()==0)
            return 0;

        count = 0;

        int i=0;
        if(reverse)
        {
            for(rit = objectMap->rbegin(); rit!=objectMap->rend() && i<start; i++, rit++);

            if(rit == objectMap->rend())
                return 0;

            return &(rit->second);
        }
        else
        {
            for(it = objectMap->begin(); it!=objectMap->end() && i<start; i++, it++);

            if(it == objectMap->end())
                return 0;

            return &(it->second);
        }
    }

    object *next()
    {
        ++ count;
        if(limit)
            if(count>limit)
                return 0;

        if(reverse)
        {
            ++ rit;
            if(rit == objectMap->rend())
                return 0;

            return &rit->second;
        }
        else
        {
            ++ it;
            if(it == objectMap->end())
                return 0;

            return &it->second;
        }
    }


    object *getAt(int x, int *pos=0)
    {
        if(objectMap->size()==0)
            return 0;

        count = 0;

        int i=0;

        if(reverse)
        {
            map<int, object>::reverse_iterator itt;

            for(itt = objectMap->rbegin(); itt!=objectMap->rend() && i<start+x; i++, itt++);

            if(itt == objectMap->rend())
                return 0;

            if(pos)
                *pos = i;

            return &itt->second;
        }
        else
        {
            map<int, object>::iterator itt;

            for(itt = objectMap->begin(); itt!=objectMap->end() && i<start+x; i++, itt++);

            if(itt == objectMap->end())
                return 0;

            if(pos)
                *pos = i;

            return &itt->second;
        }
    }

};
```

But there is an error that I don't know how to fix:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1809) : error C2784: 'reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<int,TestDataItemEx,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1856) : see declaration of 'std::operator -'
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1808) : while compiling class template member function 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::operator +(__w64 int) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _RanIt=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,TestDataItemEx,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>,false>>::iterator
1>        ]
1>        h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(510) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _RanIt=std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<int,TestDataItemEx,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>,false>>::iterator
1>        ]
1>        h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(714) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IteratorBase<object>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            object=TestDataItemEx
1>        ]
```

h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(510):

```
typename map<int, typename object, less<int>, allocator<pair<const int, typename object>>>::reverse_iterator rit;
```

h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(714):

```
class TestDataItemExIterator : public IteratorBase<struct TestDataItemEx>
```

.

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(985): error C2676: binary '-=' : 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(984) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>::operator +=(__w64 int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _RanIt=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>>>,
1>              _Base=std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>,__w64 int,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> *,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> &>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1194) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>::operator +=(__w64 int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _RanIt=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>>>,
1>              _Base=std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>,__w64 int,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> *,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> &>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(1124) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _RanIt=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>>>,
1>              _Base=std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>,__w64 int,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> *,std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx> &>
1>          ]
1>          h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(510) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _RanIt=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const int,TestDataItemEx>>>>
1>          ]
1>          h:\test.140108\test\app1\Testapp.h(714) : see reference to class template instantiation 'IteratorBase<object>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              object=TestDataItemEx
1>          ]
```

Could you help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Somewhere the code tries to compute the difference between two reverse iterators. That only works if the base iterator is a random access iterator. A map doesn't have that kind of iterator.

Comment: Thanks Bo, compute the difference between two reverse iterators is not what I want. How to prevent the code from doing that? I mean, is there any method that can use reverse iterator for map<int, object> for any struct object defined by template without a parse error?

Answer (score 1):

I have found it.
It is a Microsoft Visual Studio bug for both 2005 and 2012, don't know if it affect to other versions.
It report a compile error to a wrong place.
The real error was at the following piece of code:

```
class TestDataItemExIterator : public IteratorBase<struct TestDataItemEx>
{
    ...
};

void main()
{   
    map<int, TestDataItemEx> objectMap;

    map<int, TestDataItemEx>::reverse_iterator it=objectMap.rbegin();

    if( (it+1) != objectMap.rend()) // Here is the error location.
    {
        int i=1;
    }
}
```

However, the error report shows a different place that cost me 2 days to find the real problem place at last. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred in VS2015.
Solved it as below:

changed from:

```
*(c1.end()-1)
```

to:

```
it = c1.end();
it--;
```